# "unknown type name 'String'" when creating custom Arduino Libraries

Tags: string, arduino, libraries

I have a few logging functions that I commonly use for different Arduino programs.  Since I use them so much, I decided to try to make a custom library for them.  Unfortunately, the compiler crashes at the header file with the error:

unknown type name 'String'

I'm a bit confused as to why this is happening because I am including the standard Arduino libraries (which I believe should contain the String class) at the top of my header.  Here's the whole thing:

```
#ifndef logging_h
#define logging_h

#include "Arduino.h"

void logEvent(String msg);
void debugOut(String msg);
void errOut(String err);
void document(String parameter, float value);

#endif
```

I reinstalled the Arduino IDE (1.0.5) so I think I should have the most recent standard library.  If anyone has some suggestions I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Your code works for me in Arduino IDE 1.0.5. I was adding it as a new tab named "logging.h". What steps are you following to create your library?

Comment: Right now I just have the .h and .c files in the same directory as my main.ino.  They both show up as tabs named logging.h and logging.c respectively.  

Other than that, I haven't done anything special to create the library

Comment: Try renaming the ".c" file to ".cpp".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(This answer is based on our discussion in comments.)

The problem was that the source file for your library was named `*.c`. That caused the compiler to treat it as C code instead of C++, which means it couldn't handle classes/objects (such as `String`).

Naming the file `*.cpp` instead lets the compiler treat it correctly as C++ code.

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue yesterday. The code you included in your question should be your .h file, isn't?  My question is: **is your library written in C or in C++?**

I assume you use C code.

You can't import code from  in a user C library with the Arduino IDE. The reason is that  use C++ code, and it can't be called from your C library.

**Solution: rewrite your library in C+**, it's not too difficult.

You can find a lot of help on google on how to write library in C++. You can also check my example at https://github.com/romain-viollette/AverageFilter/

best regards,

Comment: I'm a little confused about you mean.  Do you mean that I have to rewrite my functions as a C++ class?  My understanding is that a C++ compiler should be able to compile C code, so should a library written 'in C' essentially be 'in C++'?

Comment: I was not clear enough.
 I mean that I think it's not possible to call Serial functions from a C file.
 Everything is compiled with g++ both C and C++ files. But I have noticed that When you include <Arduino.h> from a C file, as it is compiled separately, all C++ function are not included. My solution was to rewrite my library in C++, and I could import all the Arduino  libraries I want without problem. Maybe you should have a look here: http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/BuildProcess

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense.  The problem was ultimately solved by renaming my .c files to .cpp which seems consistent with your explanation.  Thanks for the help!